# NZEC error in SPOJ

Tags: java

Why am I getting runtime NZEC error in SPOJ when I paste this code?

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (t < 1 || t > 100)
        {
            t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        string[] words = new string[t];

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            string word = Console.ReadLine();
            while (word.Length > 100 || word.Length < 1)
            {
                word = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            words[i] += word; 
        }


        foreach (var item in words)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Length / 2; i+=2)
            {
                Console.Write(item[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();                
        }

    }        
}
```

I have tried every input I can think of and it runs fine. What could make this throw a non- zero error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place SPOJ submissions in a package, so remove the declaration:

```
package spoj.test;
```

The non-zero exit code probably comes from the JVM not being able to load the class to run it.